# Nested parameters on GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, url-parameters

Question of the day: how to encode URL to be able to pass complex data on a GET request?

```
# data to pass
{
    "main_key": {
        "other_key": {
            "main_array": [{
                    "name": "Bob",
                    "nickname": "bobby"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tom",
                    "nickname": "Tommy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the current solution I got with Postman

[image: postman parameters]
Here is the current Rails interpretation of such a query, which is correct.

```
# Rails server side
Parameters: {"main_key"=>{"other_key"=>{"main_array"=>[{"name"=>"Bob", "nickname"=>"bobby"}, {"name"=>"Tom", "nickname"=>"tommy"}]}}, "default"=>{"format"=>:json}}
```

Can anybody have a better way to achieve a request with such a complex nested array object?

The other solution I got is to pass JSON directly as value of a query parameter and then parse it from the controller.

**Edit: ** I can pass this json on the `body` of the request but as it's a GET method, it does not respect XHR requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery, you can use .param() method of it.

```
let myParams = {
    "main_key": {
        "other_key": {
            "main_array": [{
                    "name": "Bob",
                    "nickname": "bobby"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tom",
                    "nickname": "Tommy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

console.log($.param(myParams));
```

This will give you your desired string.

```
"main_key%5Bother_key%5D%5Bmain_array%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Bob&main_key%5Bother_key%5D%5Bmain_array%5D%5B0%5D%5Bnickname%5D=bobby&main_key%5Bother_key%5D%5Bmain_array%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=Tom&main_key%5Bother_key%5D%5Bmain_array%5D%5B1%5D%5Bnickname%5D=Tommy"
```

Comment: Nope. Here is the interpretation: `Parameters: {"\"main_key"=>{"other_key"=>{"main_array"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Bob"}}}}, "main_key"=>{"other_key"=>{"main_array"=>{"0"=>{"nickname"=>"bobby"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Tom", "nickname"=>"Tommy\""}}}}, "default"=>{"format"=>:json}}`